# std::string with ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, ostream

I am new to `ostream_iterator`. Can I use it to output strings the same way I can output integers? When I try to do that I get a C2679 error:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{ 
    std::ostream_iterator<int> i{ std::cout };
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> s{ std::cout };

    i = 1;        //prints "1"
    s = "hello";  //Generates C2679
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Add `#include <string>` at the top of your file